# XSLT for-each not able to extract values

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I'm trying to transform the xml into desired xml using xslt. But i'm not able use for - each properly and the values are returning null. Can anyone help with xslt transformation.

Here is the 
**XSLT which I'm using**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <INB>
            <SEG>
                <TRN>RAN</TRN>
                <VER>8.3</VER>
                <WHS>699</WHS>
                <xsl:for-each select="message/Lines">
                    <LINE>
                        <SENAM>LINE_SEG</SENAM>
                        <INVSLN>0</INVSLN>
                        <EXPQTY>0</EXPQTY>
                        <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(message/Lines/Nbr)) = ''">
                            <NUM>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(message/Lines/Nbr)"/>
                            </NUM>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <STS>A</STS>
                        <PRT>----</PRT>
                    </LINE>
                </xsl:for-each> 
            </SEG>
        </INB>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Here is the Input XML:**

```
<message>
    <PoNbr>451617926</PoNbr>
    <whCode/>
    <unitCode/>
    <dnrbTime/>
    <Lines>
        <Nbr>451617926</Nbr>
    </Lines>
    <Lines>
        <Nbr>2</Nbr>
    </Lines>
</message>
```

**Below is the output which it is returning**

In the below output which it is returning doesn't have the Nbr which is mapped using the for each statement.

**Output:**

```
<INB>
    <SEG>
        <TRN>RAN</TRN>
        <VER>8.3</VER>
        <WHS>699</WHS>
        <LINE>
            <SENAM>LINE_SEG</SENAM>
            <INVSLN>0</INVSLN>
            <EXPQTY>0</EXPQTY>
            <NUM/>
            <STS>A</STS>
            <PRT>----</PRT>
        </LINE>
        <LINE>
            <SENAM>LINE_SEG</SENAM>
            <INVSLN>0</INVSLN>
            <EXPQTY>0</EXPQTY>
            <NUM/>
            <STS>A</STS>
            <PRT>----</PRT>
        </LINE>
    </SEG>
</INB>
```

**Expected Output:**

```
<INB>
    <SEG>
        <TRN>RAN</TRN>
        <VER>8.3</VER>
        <WHS>699</WHS>
        <LINE>
            <SENAM>LINE_SEG</SENAM>
            <INVSLN>0</INVSLN>
            <EXPQTY>0</EXPQTY>
            <NUM>451617926</NUM>
            <STS>A</STS>
            <PRT>----</PRT>
        </LINE>
        <LINE>
            <SENAM>LINE_SEG</SENAM>
            <INVSLN>0</INVSLN>
            <EXPQTY>0</EXPQTY>
            <NUM>2</NUM>
            <STS>A</STS>
            <PRT>----</PRT>
        </LINE>
    </SEG>
</INB>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted all the XPath expressions. Check it out.

> XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/message">
        <INB>
            <SEG>
                <TRN>RAN</TRN>
                <VER>8.3</VER>
                <WHS>699</WHS>
                <xsl:for-each select="Lines">
                    <LINE>
                        <SENAM>LINE_SEG</SENAM>
                        <INVSLN>0</INVSLN>
                        <EXPQTY>0</EXPQTY>
                        <xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(Nbr)) = ''">
                            <NUM>
                                <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(Nbr)"/>
                            </NUM>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <STS>A</STS>
                        <PRT>----</PRT>
                    </LINE>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </SEG>
        </INB>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

> Output XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<INB>
  <SEG>
    <TRN>RAN</TRN>
    <VER>8.3</VER>
    <WHS>699</WHS>
    <LINE>
      <SENAM>LINE_SEG</SENAM>
      <INVSLN>0</INVSLN>
      <EXPQTY>0</EXPQTY>
      <NUM>451617926</NUM>
      <STS>A</STS>
      <PRT>----</PRT>
    </LINE>
    <LINE>
      <SENAM>LINE_SEG</SENAM>
      <INVSLN>0</INVSLN>
      <EXPQTY>0</EXPQTY>
      <NUM>2</NUM>
      <STS>A</STS>
      <PRT>----</PRT>
    </LINE>
  </SEG>
</INB>
```

Comment: This solution fails to fix the error pointed out by @AjeetSingh in the `test` expression. The expression `not(normalize-space(Nbr))` returns false on this dataset. Comparing false to "" is an error under XPath 2.0, but returns true under XPath 1.0. So it's working (on this data) by accident -- a classic example of why the stronger type checking in XPath 2.0 is desirable.

Comment: Incidentally the idiom `test="normalize-space(Nbr)"` works on both 1.0 and 2.0. Some people don't like the implicit string->boolean conversion, and indeed I don't, but this idiom is so common and handy that I'm comfortable to use it. And Saxon optimizes it - it doesn't actually construct the normalized string, just tests whether there are any non-space characters.

Answer (score 2):

only Change following code

```
<xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(message/Lines/Nbr)) = ''">
```

change to

```
<xsl:if test="not(normalize-space(message/Lines/Nbr)='')">
```

Comment: Also need to fix the main bug; the main bug is the common one of failing to understand that `xsl:for-each` changes the context.